# How to compare nm outputs

Tags: c++, linux, g++, nm

I have 2 object files which are supposed to be similar as they are from 2 different compilation times from same code base. I wanted to compare their nm outputs. However I cant as there is lot of name mangling . Due to name mangling results seem to be different but they are actually not. I tried the following steps to help me compare

```
1) took last word using command
sed '/ /s/.* //' nmfile1 >nmfile1_lastword

2) removed _Z.. starting word with nothing 
sed 's/^_Z...//' nmfile1_lastword > nmfile1_lastword_removed_z

3) sorted the same 
sort nmfile1_lastword_removed_z > nmfile1_lastword_removed_z_sorted
```

I did the above for second nmFile2 as well .

However there is still lots of name mangling at the start which I am unable to remove which makes me think is there no simple way to compare nm outputs . Do note that I am concerned just with the starting name mangling as then I could see the results in gvim -d and I would be able to identify differences manually. If there is some direct tool it would be best .

Please note that I tried using nm with option  -C  to show me without name Mangling but it still shows a lot of name mangling .

Answer (score 1):

use c++filt to de-mangle symbols as

```
nm xxx.so | c++filt > compare1.txt
nm xxx.so | c++filt > compare2.txt
```

Comment: what platform? can have access to sample binary?

Comment: Sorry wont be able to share binary .. I am using linux with g++ . the OS specs are : Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseClient
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.10 
Release:        5.10

Comment: ok can you pass one mangle string which is not processed by c++file e.g $c++filt _ZNK3MapI10StringName3RefI8GDScriptE10ComparatorIS0_E16DefaultAllocatorE3hasERKS0_

Comment: looks like nm version you are using has bug. quick solution is demangle your binaries on latest tools (nm). for reference http://sourcery.mentor.com/archives/cxx-abi-dev/msg02295.html